# Filtering using a string value in where clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have a `DataSet` which contains items as:

```
X0101
X0202
X0303
...
```

On page load I retrieve all of them and I need to filter them based on the combobox value which has been selected and for that I do:

```
protected void cmbUniqueID_Callback(object sender, DevExpress.Web.CallbackEventArgsBase e)
{
    string selectedID = e.Parameter;
    DataSet dataSet = GetAllUniqueIDs();

    var fullList = dataSet?.Tables[0]
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(x => new
         {
            UniqueID = x.Field<string>("UniqueID")
         });

   var filteredList = from r in fullList where r.UniqueID >= selectedID select r;

   cmbUniqueID.DataSource = filteredList;
   cmbUniqueID.DataBind();

}
```

But I get the following error:

> Error CS0019  Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

For example if user selects `X0101` then only `X0202 & X0303` remain in the filtered list.

Can someone tell me how I can filter the data.

Comment: `selectedID` is a string. What does the `>=`  operator should do for string?

Comment: Are `X0101` etc. the Unique IDs? Because how do you know if `X0101` is greater than `X1234`?

Comment: @NibblyPig Yes they are the unique IDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your IDs are not numbers, you cannot do a mathematical comparison.

If your IDs are always the same length and format (letter + 4 numbers) then you can just parse out the number part.

You could use regex but a quick way to do it would be:

`UniqueID = int.Parse(x.Field<string>("UniqueID").Substring(1))`

This will give you the numeric part. You will have to add the `X` back in later on. Or you could add a separate field for the numeric part in your anonymous type.

Alternatively, rather than altering the source to be numeric to allow the mathematical operation, it would be much nicer if you changed your `.Where`.

You could do

`where int.Parse(r.UniqueID.Substring(1)) >= int.Parse(selectedID.Substring(1))`

which would compare the numeric parts.

Alternatively you could write your own method to compare the two if you want different logic, or if your IDs change format.

And based on the last part of your question, you probably want `=` rather than `>=`, because the latter would be inclusive of the option you selected.

Answer (score -1):

I have checked the code, only thing you need to do is change the where clause operator.

```
private void FilterData()
    {
        string selectedID = "X0101";
        DataSet dataSet = GetAllUniqueIDs();

        var fullList = dataSet?.Tables[0]
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(x => new
            {
                UniqueID = x.Field<string>("UniqueID")
            });

        var filteredList = from r in fullList where Convert.ToInt64(r.UniqueID.Substring(1)) > Convert.ToInt64(selectedID.Substring(1)) select r;
    }

    private DataSet GetAllUniqueIDs()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("UniqueID");

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["UniqueID"] = "X0101";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["UniqueID"] = "X0202";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["UniqueID"] = "X0303";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dt.AcceptChanges();
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        return ds;
    }
```

Comment: `!=` will not produce the expected behaviour